# Storing html input of type time into MySQL database

Tags: html, mysql, datetime, time

hope you fine and well,

i have an html form that contains input of type time, what is the better datatype that i can use to store the input value in MySQL ?!

below is the input:

```
<td align="center">Time<input type="time" name="start">
```

i used varchar type, but i think it will cause problems in the future if i need to compare stored time with current time for example.

i didn't used datetime because i just have time only and no need for date.

so, any suggestions?

Comment: [The `TIME` Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this, still by storing datetime when you create your database (maybe you will need date later for any kind of test ) but when you want to retrive it just use the right format like this :

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colName,'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY
```

**Edit** : you can use time format as well :

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(colName, 'HH:MM:SS')
```

For more information about how to format you can checkout [datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and [time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is [Time Type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) Which you can use.

MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in `HH:MM:SS` format (or `HHH:MM:SS` format for large hours values). TIME values may range from `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`.